# Test discovery: list all tests in a format suitable for copy/paste

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I have a bunch of tests. I can run them with:

```
./manage.py test
```

which will perform test discovery and run all tests for me. Fine. Now I want to run a specific test:

```
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak
```

Can I get some help on typing that *on the command line*? The shell will not help, because:

- it uses slashes instead of dots
- it does not know about unittest module (of course), so can not take a look inside `animals/tests.py`

The maximum that the shell will help me with (by using tab completion) is something like:

```
$ ./manage.py test animals/tests.py
```

Which does not help me at all. I would like something like:

```
$ ./manage.py discover-tests

animals
animals.tests
animals.tests.AnimalTestCase
animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak
...
```

Basically, I would like to get the list of the tests discoverd by django (unittest?) shown to me, instead of being run, so that I can manually select one, copy/paste and run it.

Is there a way of achieving that, or do I need to roll my own `discover-tests`?

Comment: The correct form is ./manage.py test animals.tests.file_name.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak (where the file name should be without the .py extension)

Comment: The testcases are in this case in `animals/tests.py`, so the "filename" is `tests.py`. Maybe not the best choice, but not relevant for this question

Comment: So ./manage.py test animals.tests.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak  ought to work in Django 1.8

Comment: Ok, maybe you are right. I am typing all this by hand, so maybe there is an error (I think not, but whatever). But this is not relevant. My question is : *what is the command to get a list of the available tests, in a format suitable for copy-paste?*

Comment: Verified: the test is called `animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak`, if your testcase is in `animals/tests.py` (make sure you do not have an `animals/tests` directory)

Comment: THe answer to that is there isn't one AFAIK (which you can double check by looking at ./manage.py help followed by ./manage.py help test)

Comment: Yeah, I already checked that, that's why I am asking here. Maybe another tool? Maybe calling unittest directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default test runner does not (AFAIK) have the ability to provide a list of all available tests. However the third party test framework [nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) has a collect option that can do this for you.

The other option is to create your own test runner by extending the django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner to create a new test runner that has this feature. You will of course need to add your own command to manage.py as well.

Alternatively if you don't want to spend too much time on it, add a line of code to DiscoverRunner to print each test it discovers. You can save the output.